# how to find datalist item which cause the command event

Tags: c#, asp.net, nested-datalist

I am having `nested-datalist` and on child `datalist`, `itemcommand` event I am doing some thing like this

```
if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
{
    string keyID;

    int idx = e.Item.ItemIndex;
    DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    DataList dl = Session["dl"] as DataList;
    object thisKey = dl.DataKeys[idx];

    keyID = thisKey.ToString();
    foreach (DataListItem item in dl.Items)
    {
        LinkButton lb = item.FindControl("LinkButton1") as LinkButton;
        ImageButton ib = item.FindControl("ImageButton1") as ImageButton;
        string s = item.ItemIndex.ToString();
        string j = s;
        if (item.ItemIndex == idx)
        {
           string dds = ib.AlternateText;
           Label ServiceCommentIDLabel = item.FindControl("ServiceCommentIDLabel") as Label;
           string ds = ServiceCommentIDLabel.Text;
           ServiceComment sc = db.ServiceComments.Where(o => o.ServiceCommentID == long.Parse(ServiceCommentIDLabel.Text)).First();
           db.ServiceComments.DeleteOnSubmit(sc);
           Response.Redirect("Services.aspx");
        }
     }
 }
```

Neither its picking the exact `datakey` nor `foreach` loop traversing through each `item` of `datalist`.

Comment: why you have used `c` tag in your question. it should be `C#` as I think?

Comment: sorry mistakenly taged c, i edited the post thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `DataList` from `Session` which not good thing. You have to convert `DataList` from `Object` source in `ItemCommand` event like this:

```
protected void Child_DataList_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        // get DataList from the source
        DataList dl = source as DataList;

        object thisKey = dl.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex];
        // do your work here
    }
}
```